# F# string.Format

Tags: f#

I am writing my first F# library

I am trying to use `string.Format` and it complains that no such function exists.

Is it not available or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If you want to avoid using the full name, you can use `open` in F#:

```
open System
let s = String.Format("Hello {0}", "world")
```

This should work in both F# interactive (enter the `open` clause first) and in normal compiled applications. The key thing is that you must write `String` with upper-case `S`. This is because `string` in C# isn't a usual type name - it is a keyword refering to the `System.String` type.

Alternatively, you could also take a look at the `sprintf` function. It is an F#-specific alternative to `String.Format` which has some nice benefits - for example it is type checked:

```
let s = sprintf "Hello %s! Number is %d" "world" 42
```

The compiler will check that the parameters (string and int) match the format specifiers (`%s` for string and `%d` for integers). The function also works better in scenarios where you want to use partial function application:

```
let nums = [ 1 .. 10 ]
let formatted = nums |> List.map (sprintf "number %d")
```

This will produce a list of strings containing "number 1", "number 2" etc... If you wanted to do this using `String.Format`, you'd have to explicitly write a lambda function.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice for suggesting `sprintf`, which is a better option most of the time.

Comment: `sprint` is certainly more idiomatic, but it may be slower when called frequently in some loop...

Comment: Wow—I'm surprised at just [how slow `sprintf` is in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742189/performance-of-sprintf-vs-string-format). Good point.

Comment: @Jordan: Starting with F# 3.1, sprintf runs up to 40x faster (see "Printf performance" [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)).

Comment: C# 6 string interpolation is so nice.  It seems like it belongs in F#.  Wish it were shared.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 string interpolation is under discussion for F#. cf https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1001-StringInterpolation.md

Answer (score 3):

the full name of it is:

```
System.String.Format
```

Comment: I mean open System, C# stuffed everywhere :)