# Performance of sprintf vs String.Format

Tags: .net, string, performance, f#

I was comparing the performance of sprintf usages and am a little troubled by what I saw.  I tested the following 4 methods, passing an instance of ClassWithToString in to each (except for PrintInt, which received the actual integer value).

```
type ClassWithToString() =
    member this.X = 42
    override this.ToString() = this.X.ToString()

let Print item : string =
    sprintf "%A" item

let PrintInt item: string =
    sprintf "%i" item

let PrintObj item: string =
    sprintf "%O" item

let Format item : string =
    System.String.Format("{0}", item)
```

The results for 50,000 iterations:

```
Print (%A):     3143ms
PrintInt (%i):   355ms
PrintObj (%O):   384ms
Format:            8ms
```

For "Print," I understand %A is using reflection so the sluggishness there is not shocking, though for 50k iterations I was surprised at the total time.  Following that, "PrintInt" and "PrintObj" do not use reflection and thus are an order of magnitude faster, which also makes sense.

The part that confounds me is that in light of the results of `String.Format()` sprintf in general appears to be dreadfully slow (and has been witnessed in profiles of live applications).  Why is sprintf magnitudes slower than String.Format()?  Is there a better alternative in the F# space that I've missed?

Comment: Since you already know it uses Reflection, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Compare the [`printf` source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs) with that of `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`. `printf` does a lot more, for example, recursive collection printing.

Comment: Only %A uses reflection.  %i would be the base case.

Comment: This fits the typical question of "why is x so much slower than y".  With the common answer, "x isn't slow, y is just heavily optimized to be fast".  Certainly the case for composite string formatting in .NET, big chunks of it live inside the CLR in hand-tuned C++ code.  And the corollary, use a profiler to *know* if you need to address it.  With high odds for no, strings are for I/O and that's already slow.  Hey, that rhymes well ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Only %A uses reflection. %i would be the base case.

It's not true. All `printf` functions need reflection to construct type-safe printing functions from format strings, no matter which specifiers you use. Take a look at [this line](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs#L319) and [this line](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs#L215) from `printf` module for more insights. So it's easy to see why `sprintf "%i"` is still slower than `String.Format`.
In the case of `sprintf "%A"`, it has one more level of reflection which explains its dreadful slowness.

> Is there a better alternative in the F# space that I've missed?

If your purpose is to construct big strings, [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) and [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) are probably the ways to go. If you benchmark for logging purpose, [FastPrintf](http://t0yv0.blogspot.com/2012/09/faster-printf-released-on-nuget.html) is a promising library. You can try out [this NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/FastPrintf/) which claims to be 100x faster than the built-in `printf` functions.