# Iterating through a calendar in F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, string-formatting, c#-to-f#

```cs
for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= gregorianCalendar.GetMonthsInYear(gregorianCalendar.GetYear(startOfYear)); ctr++) {
    Console.Write(" {0,2}", ctr);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,12}{1,15:MMMM}",
                      gregorianCalendar.GetDaysInMonth(gregorianCalendar.GetYear(startOfMonth), gregorianCalendar.GetMonth(startOfMonth)),
                      startOfMonth);
    startOfMonth = gregorianCalendar.AddMonths(startOfMonth, 1);
}
```

I was trying to write the same code in F# but I don't know what `{0, 2}` and `{0,12}{1,15:MMMM}` is, what they do and what F# equivalent of these are. The main target here is F# equivalent of C# code above. But, I would be glad if you explain formats above shortly.

**Notes:**

- `gregorianCalendar` is an instance of `System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar`.
- `startOfYear` is an instance of `DateTime` which has value of `DateTime(2023, 1, 1)`.
- `startOfMonth` is an instance of `DateTime` which has value same as value of `startOfYear` at initialization. It's used to loop through months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few different translations, from trying to change as little as possible to getting more advanced

```
open System
open System.Globalization
let now, today = DateTime.Now, DateTime.Today
let startOfYear = DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1)
let g = GregorianCalendar()
let range = [1.. g.GetMonthsInYear(g.GetYear(startOfYear))]
let runViaFor() =
    let mutable startOfMonth = today.AddDays(float (-1* (today.Day - 1)))
    for ctr in range do
        printf "%2i" ctr
        printfn "%12i%15s" (g.GetDaysInMonth(g.GetYear(startOfMonth), g.GetMonth(startOfMonth))) (startOfMonth.ToString("MMMM"))
        startOfMonth <- g.AddMonths(startOfMonth, 1)
    ()
let runViaSeq() =
    let mutable startOfMonth = today.AddDays(float (-1* (today.Day - 1)))
    range
    |> Seq.iter(fun ctr ->
        printf "%2i" ctr
        printfn "%12i%15s" (g.GetDaysInMonth(g.GetYear(startOfMonth), g.GetMonth(startOfMonth))) (startOfMonth.ToString("MMMM"))
        startOfMonth <- g.AddMonths(startOfMonth, 1)
    )
let runViaFold() =
    let startOfMonth = today.AddDays(float (-1* (today.Day - 1)))
    (startOfMonth, range)
    ||> Seq.fold(fun startOfMonth ctr ->
        printf "%2i" ctr
        printfn "%12i%15s" (g.GetDaysInMonth(g.GetYear(startOfMonth), g.GetMonth(startOfMonth))) (startOfMonth.ToString("MMMM"))
        g.AddMonths(startOfMonth, 1)
    )
    |> ignore<DateTime>
    
let withRefactors today =
    let addDays (dt:DateTime) (i:int) = float i |> dt.AddDays
    let getStartOfMonth(dt:DateTime) = dt.Day - 1 |> (*) -1 |> addDays dt
    
    let getLastDayOfMonth(startOfMonth:DateTime) = 
        let year = g.GetYear(startOfMonth)
        let month = g.GetMonth(startOfMonth)
        g.GetDaysInMonth(year, month)
    let printRow (startOfMonth:DateTime) ctr =
        printf "%2i" ctr
        printfn "%12i%15s" (getLastDayOfMonth startOfMonth) (startOfMonth.ToString("MMMM"))
    let printAndGet startOfMonth ctr =
        printRow startOfMonth ctr
        g.AddMonths(startOfMonth, 1)
        
        
    (getStartOfMonth today, range)
    ||> Seq.fold printAndGet
    |> ignore<DateTime>
printfn "For:"    
runViaFor()
printfn "----"
printfn "Seq:"
runViaSeq()
printfn "----"
printfn "Fold:"
runViaFold()
printfn "----"
printfn "Ref:"
withRefactors today
printfn "----"
```

sample output:
[image: codesnippetimg]

Answer (score 1):

`{0, 2}` and `{0,12}{1,15:MM}` are [format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0).

In this case, `{0, 2}` will control the width of `ctr` (in this case, 2 characters long).

`{0,12}{1,15:MM}` will take the output from `gregorianCalendar.GetDaysInMonth` and format it into a 12-character string and `startOfMonth` will be a 15-character string (starting at index 1) with full month name (`MMMM` provides the full month name for the provided date).

See here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting.

I don't know F# but I imagine it is not too different. See here, perhaps, for an example: [F# string.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979178/f-string-format).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a literal translation into F#, it looks very similar:

```ml
open System
open System.Globalization

let gregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar()
let startOfYear = DateTime(2023, 1, 1)
let mutable startOfMonth = startOfYear

for ctr = 1 to gregorianCalendar.GetMonthsInYear(gregorianCalendar.GetYear(startOfYear)) do
    Console.Write(" {0,2}", ctr)
    Console.WriteLine("{0,12}{1,15:MMMM}",
                      gregorianCalendar.GetDaysInMonth(gregorianCalendar.GetYear(startOfMonth), gregorianCalendar.GetMonth(startOfMonth)),
                      startOfMonth)
    startOfMonth <- gregorianCalendar.AddMonths(startOfMonth, 1)
```

However, many F# developers prefer to avoid mutable variables and side-effects. So the following is more idiomatic:

```ml
    // compute month starts with no side-effects
let nMonths = gregorianCalendar.GetMonthsInYear(gregorianCalendar.GetYear(startOfYear))
let startsOfMonths =
    (startOfYear, [| 1 .. nMonths-1 |])
        ||> Array.scan (fun startOfMonth _ ->
            gregorianCalendar.AddMonths(startOfMonth, 1))

    // write results to console
for ctr = 1 to nMonths do
    let startOfMonth = startsOfMonths[ctr-1]
    Console.Write(" {0,2}", ctr)
    Console.WriteLine("{0,12}{1,15:MMMM}",
                        gregorianCalendar.GetDaysInMonth(gregorianCalendar.GetYear(startOfMonth), gregorianCalendar.GetMonth(startOfMonth)),
                        startOfMonth)
```